# FFMPEG: transcode interlaced J2K

Tags: ffmpeg, video, transcode

i've been tasked with developing a solution using ffmpeg that will transcode archival videos into FFV1.  the videos are all JPEG2000, but some are uncompressed and others are compressed.  as the original source files are interlaced, we need to conserve the same interlacing for the transcoded files.

the problem i'm running into is that transcoding the uncompressed j2k results in ffv1 video files with expected file sizes, but strangely, transcoding the others results in files that are even bigger than the j2k source files -- almost twice as big, in fact.  i'm pretty sure this is because the video bitrate (and B/PI values, as reported by [mediainfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo)) are twice as large as the source.  try as i might, i can't come up with a video that has a similar bitrate and pixel storage density (and similar size) even after having tried a number of different ways to do this, including using intermediary uncompressed files.

i'm now looking at the following question: is the compression format used on the source file really that much better than ffv1, or am i missing something really fundamental?  i'm inclined to think it's the latter, but by now i feel like i'm shooting in the dark.  any help would be appreciated.

### **here is some supplementary info:**

- mediainfo report of the source file:

```
Format                                   : MXF
Format version                           : 1.3
File size                                : 5,81 Gib
Duration                                 : 17 min 45s
Overall bit rate                         : 46.8 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 25.000 Im/s
Video
Format                                   : JPEG 2000
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16/9
Frame rate                               : 25.000 Im/s
Original frame rate                      : 50.000 Im/s
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan order                               : Top field first
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 4.067
```

(there are also 2 audio tracks and 3 timecode tracks, not represented here.)

- doing a straightforward transcode of the first 60s into ffv1 doesn't work; the resulting video is progressive, and one of the requirements is that interlacing be preserved.  so using `tinterlace`, i get a file with the following characteristics:

```
General
Format                                   : Matroska
Format version                           : Version 4
File size                                : 670 MiB
Duration                                 : 1 min 0 s
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 93.7 Mb/s
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Video
Format                                   : FFV1
Format version                           : Version 3.4
Format settings, GOP                     : N=1
Width                                    : 720 pixels
Height                                   : 576 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Standard                                 : PAL
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:2
Bit depth                                : 10 bits
Scan type                                : Interlaced
Scan order                               : Top Field First
Compression mode                         : Lossless
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 8.411
```

the bit storage density is twice that of the source video (8.4 vs. 4.1) as is the bitrate.  here is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i $input -t 60 \
    -c:v ffv1 -level 3 -threads 8 -slices 4 -slicecrc 1 -g 1 \
    -pix_fmt yuv422p10le \
    -vf tinterlace=0 \
    -c:a copy -c:d copy -c:s copy -c:t copy \
    -map 0 -y $output
```

- i tried transcoding the source file into a completely uncompressed v210+avi intermediary file, then transcoding that into ffv1.  the first 60s of v210 weighed in at 1.57Gb.  transcoding that to ffv1 resulted in a 673Mb file whose bitrate and B/PI were, once again, over twice the original (94.1Mbps and 8.45 respectively).
- i tried extracting to PNG and then re-integrating the images.  as with the `tinterlace` filter above, this produces a video that is roughly twice as big as the original. bitrate 90Mbps, B/PI 8.1.
- i've also tried many other approaches, including throttling the bitrate with `-crf`, `-b:v`, `-maxrate`, etc (apparently not taken into account for ffv1), using various combinations of `interlace` and `tinterlace` and their parametres, alone and in combination with `scale`.  nothing works.

am i trying to squeeze orange juice from an apple?  or am i just not using the right command options?